# 'Router'/'GlobalStyles' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having this issue on my React application:

```
'Router' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Router' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
```

It's also happening on a *Global Styles* component I created

```
'GlobalStyles' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Component<ThemedGlobalStyledClassProps<{}>
```

*This is my App.tsx file:*

```js
import {BrowserRouter, Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Slide, ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

import Routes from "./routes";
import GlobalStyles from "./styles/global";

import Header from "./components/Header";
import Aside from "./components/Aside";

import { CartProvider } from "./hooks/useCart";

import history from "./history";

import { AuthProvider } from "./Context/AuthContext";


const App = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      <Aside />
      <AuthProvider>
        <Router history={history}>
          <CartProvider>
            <GlobalStyles />
            <Header />
            <Routes />
            <ToastContainer autoClose={3000} transition={Slide} />
          </CartProvider>
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I'm using the version 18 of React and there's what I've tried so far:

- Deleting node_modules and running yarn install
- Reverting React version to 17~
- Reinstalling React and React Router

Comment: The error tells itself what the problem is. It's not a jsx component and therefore it can't be rendered. What's GlobalStyles? CSS? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, GlobalStyles is a stylesheet file. Even if I don't specify the return as a JSX.Component the error keeps coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First at all you have to import BrowserRouter as Router like the following code:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, } from "react-router-dom";
```

GlobalStyles probably it not a component.

Here two way to create a component in React.

1-) Function Components must be like following:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

2-) Class Components:

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `styled-components` might be using old versions of `@types/react`. You can confirm by checking the version of react types in `node_modules/types/styled-components`.

For me adding `yarn resolutions` helped to solve the problem (if you are using `yarn` as well).

Try adding this to your `package.json` file.

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0"
  }
```

Unfortunately it will (might???) not work if you are using `npm`.